# Users authentication lose when I publish an ASP.NET Core aplication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Every time I publish an ASP.NET 5 (Core) application my users need to login again.
In ASP.NET 4 I have Session State Server, but I haven't in ASP.NET 5 Core.
How can I keep users logged when I publish a new version of my application?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you authenticate your users?

Comment: And how do you publish and host the app? Do you use cookie authentication?

Comment: Hi!, I use cookie authentication and when I publish I delete all the files and put new ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found this way:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview

And works!!
Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Can you explain how did you solve it?

Comment: Hi!, follow this instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview